# Is lucid dreaming haram?

Tags: halal-haram, dream

As defined by Wikipedia a lucid dream is…

> …any dream in which one is aware that one is dreaming.
>
> The phenomenon had also been referred to by Greek philosopher
>   Aristotle who had observed:
>
> > often when one is asleep, there is something in consciousness which
> >     declares that what then presents itself is but a dream.
>
> One of the earliest references to personal experiences with lucid
>   dreaming was by Marie-Jean-Léon, Marquis d'Hervey de Saint Denys. The
>   person most widely acknowledged as having coined the term is Dutch
>   psychiatrist and writer Frederik (Willem) van Eeden (1860–1932).
>
> In a lucid dream, the dreamer has greater chances to exert some degree
>   of control over their participation within the dream or be able to
>   manipulate their imaginary experiences in the dream environment. Lucid
>   dreams can be realistic and vivid. It is shown that there are higher
>   amounts of beta-1 frequency band (13–19 Hz) experienced by lucid
>   dreamers, hence there is an increased amount of activity in the
>   parietal lobes making lucid dreaming a conscious process.
>
> Skeptics of the phenomenon suggest that it is not a state of sleep,
>   but of brief wakefulness. Others point out that there is no way to
>   prove the truth of lucid dreaming other than to ask the dreamer. Lucid
>   dreaming has been researched scientifically, with test subjects
>   performing pre-determined physical responses while experiencing a
>   lucid dream.

Is lucid dreaming haram?

Comment: No it isn't Haram as stated in the answers below, I myself do this too, it's part of an dream it may feel real but there are not effects on the world. Allah created for us the ability to dream, so lucid dreaming is also from his creation.  He built it in us as halal, it's part of us. The Prophets also had dreams of things that are going to happen which is likely to be a lucid dream because a normal dream woudnt be so memorizable

Comment: Haram according to who?  Why would you think that this is something that would even need a ruling?  As phrased, this question shows no actual research effort.  See also relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/663/22

Comment: i have read that some people intentionally bring themselves into lucid dream, with using some technics and training. if it is indeed possible, that is not natural , so it is not something made by god, and we should not change what allah made.

Answer (score 8):

Dreams or as you said Lucid dreams occur when one is sleeping.

There is a hadith which states that

> It was narrated from ‘Aa’ishah that the Prophet (peace and blessings
>   of Allaah be upon him) said: “The Pen has been lifted from three: from
>   the sleeping person until he wakes up, from the minor until he grows
>   up, and from the insane person until he comes to his senses.” Narrated
>   by Abu Dawood (4398), al-Nisaa’i (3432) and Ibn Maajah (2041); classed
>   as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

If you are having a lucid dream,this means you are definitely sleeping,therefore whatever happens in that dream won`t be written in your book of deeds.

Moreover,no matter how much control you have in your Lucid dream,it is still a dream,which means that you are watching that stuff in your mind! The visions can be your thoughts or your astral body,but it isn't your actual physical body doing the actions.Therefore its all in a persons mind and whatever is inside our mind,won`t be written in the book of deeds unless that thought materialises by your actions!

In short Lucid dreaming cannot be haram (as i am not a scholar myself, just giving my personal opinion based on the knowledge i have), and
Allah knows the best

Comment: Salam. Could you add a reference link to the hadith you mentioned and improve the formatting a bit? That would greatly improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be on action for it to be written in our book of deeds, desires happen inside our minds and if it were wrong we will pay for it.  If someone for example is imagining having intercourse with a dead corpse,  do you say that that's okay by Allah as long as he didn't actually do it?

When it comes to lucid dreaming you can actually bring some character from real life to your dream and do with it whatever you desire, and because in lucid dreaming you're actually conscious,  this is will be handled as if it's a will, "*Neeiah*" so be aware of that and don't practice what's *haram* in real life while lucid dreaming because having thoughts or imagining yourself doing intercourse with a woman you saw will be counted as a will, and that's *haram*.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange.  Answers are meant to directly answer the question asked.  They are not to be used to respond to or seek clarification from other users; use comments ([an earned privilege](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)) for that.  I would also recommend you read our [about] page to better understand the Stack Exchange model and how we differ from a typical Internet forum.

Answer (score 0):

Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala only punishes you for your actions and not your thoughts. So until your thoughts become your actions then nothing will be recorded for you. Allah is all patient and forgiving. He give you a chance to ponder a sin and if you turn away from it you get good deeds if you ACT upon it you get bad deeds.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum wa Rahmatullahi wa Barakatu.
All praise and thanks is due to Allah.
The pen being lifted from a person is due to their inability to properly think about and control their actions which is the case for the child, sleeper, and insane. lucid dreaming though more closely resembles day dreaming, and includes conscious thoughts and decisions, and therefore one should not purposefully dream about doing forbidden things, as one is only pardoned for these thoughts unconsciously entering their mind but if they entertain them and fantisise then this is haram, as the Prophet (peace be upon him has said) 'what leads to haram is also haram' and that 'the thoughts become actions' Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala says in the Quran:

> 'don't go near zina' 'indeed it is a horrible path'.

So dreaming about doing such things is wrong and it may cause you to become less able to restrain yourself in real life. InshaAllah this helps you, i apologise for not knowing the verse numbers and surah, there is a video series on youtube by ustadh Nouman Ali Khan called Shame series, which comprehensively explains these verses and the whole topic of moral and immoral behaviour

JazakAllah Khairan for reading. May Allah guide us all to the straight path and make us pleasing to Him and enter us into Jannah