# Is having inappropriate dreams haram?

Tags: halal-haram, dream

Recently I had an incident were I was lucid dreaming and there was a naked women in front of me. I did not immediately wake up until about 30 seconds into it. Could this be interpreted as porn therefore making it haram?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: As long as you don't have the ability to guide or control your dreams in the right direction intentionally I can't even imagine how this can be haram! However this question has been asked before http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/is-lucid-dreaming-haram

Answer (score 1):

No, having lucid dreams isn't haram. Lucid dreams happen when people sleep. Actions during sleep are not recorded according to the following narration:

> Narrated Aisha, Ummul Mu'minin:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: There are three (persons) whose
>   actions are not recorded: a sleeper till he awakes, an idiot till he
>   is restored to reason, and a boy till he reaches puberty.
>
> Grade: Sahih (Al-Albani), Reference: [Sunan Abi Dawud 4398](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/48)