# does prohibited act inside conscious dreaming (Lucid dreaming) is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, dream

> A lucid dream is a dream during which the dreamer is aware that they are dreaming.[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream).

i read also there is low and high lucid dream. in low state the dreamer is conscious but the environment of dream is given. at the high state, the dreamer can control and change the environment, even manifest their imagination.

my question here is, this ability often used to find sexual fulfilment. it is easy at high state to summon a pretty girl or actrees, and do something  with her. Does this act is okay or considered haram?

i have read this thread [Is lucid dreaming haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/is-lucid-dreaming-haram?rq=1). i know a hadith that the point is everything inside a dream is not counted. but i tend to consider what prophet means there isn't lucid dreaming. because in lucid dreaming there is **Consciousness**. and every conscious act is counted.

Any opinion guys? btw forgive my grammar

Answer (score -1):

Yes brother it is haram.
In lucid dreaming if you have consiuosness and control then yes it is haram because it is no longer a dream, it is the same as normal imagination. 
Here is a source: https://islamqa.info/en/182280

Comment: can't read arabic lol

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/182280

Comment: Your reference say that believing that one can control a dream is kufr. I don't see where you read that this is haram as the word haram isn't even mentioned once in the whole text!